# Custom function to replace missing values in dataframe with median located in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, pivot-table

I am attempting to write a function to replace missing values in the 'total_income' column with the median 'total_income' provided by the pivot table, using the row's 'education' and 'income_type' to index the pivot table. I want to populate using these medians so that the values are as optimal as they can be. Here is what I am testing:

```
This is the first 5 rows of the dataframe as a dictionary:
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'children': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 0},
 'days_employed': {0: 8437.673027760233,
  1: 4024.803753850451,
  2: 5623.422610230956,
  3: 4124.747206540018,
  4: 340266.07204682194},
 'dob_years': {0: 42, 1: 36, 2: 33, 3: 32, 4: 53},
 'education': {0: "bachelor's degree",
  1: 'secondary education',
  2: 'secondary education',
  3: 'secondary education',
  4: 'secondary education'},
 'education_id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'family_status': {0: 'married',
  1: 'married',
  2: 'married',
  3: 'married',
  4: 'civil partnership'},
 'family_status_id': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'gender': {0: 'F', 1: 'F', 2: 'M', 3: 'M', 4: 'F'},
 'income_type': {0: 'employee',
  1: 'employee',
  2: 'employee',
  3: 'employee',
  4: 'retiree'},
 'debt': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'total_income': {0: 40620.102,
  1: 17932.802,
  2: 23341.752,
  3: 42820.568,
  4: 25378.572},
 'purpose': {0: 'purchase of the house',
  1: 'car purchase',
  2: 'purchase of the house',
  3: 'supplementary education',
  4: 'to have a wedding'},
 'age_group': {0: 'adult',
  1: 'adult',
  2: 'adult',
  3: 'adult',
  4: 'older adult'}}

def fill_income(row):
    total_income = row['total_income']
    age_group =  row['age_group']
    income_type = row['income_type']
    education = row['education']
    table = df.pivot_table(index=['age_group','income_type' ], columns='education', values='total_income', aggfunc='median')


    if total_income == 'NaN':
        if age_group =='adult':
            return table.loc[education, income_type]
```

My desired output is the pivot table value (the median total_income) for the dataframe row's given education and income_type. When I test it, it returns 'None'.

Thanks in advance for your time helping me with this problem!

Comment: please provide an example of the data. it is helpful to ask in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the variable `df` is not defined. presumably this is the dataframe itself.

Comment: Hi, I added the file path! sorry about that

Comment: The file path is useless for us because... we cant access your file anyway. Provide entire or at least part of your dataframe (not an image) like this we can copy/paste into our own IDE to try to reproduce the error. And show us an expected result/output.

Comment: Ah I see, I added the first 5 rows of the dataframe as a dictionary. Thank you for the edit!